# how to loop the State from 1 to 100 in react state

Tags: reactjs, loops

I want the state of my react application to go from 1 - 100 something like this

```
this.state = {
          items: [
            {id:1, name:'User 1', age:27},
            {id:2, name:'User 2', age:30},
            {id:3, name:'User 3', age:40}
          ]
```

I know i have to use map of some of the loops but nothings comes to mind. Please i will be very appriciative if you can help me with this one

Comment: you want to add new items with `incrementing` `id` property {id:100, name:'User 1', age:27} `OR` you want to iterate through this array of objects using map

Comment: I was thinking of using map but how to get to 100

Comment: this.state.items.map((item, index) => { if(item.id === 100) console.log(item); })

Comment: @EmirMustafoski u want to add 1-100 item in items list?

Comment: Please explain it better. You want to add 100 objects to state? or search for the object with id = 100?

Answer (score 0):

If you like to modify or access the first 100 items from your state:

```
this.state.items.forEach((item, index) => {
  if(item.id <= 100){
  //do stuff
 }
}
```

If you would like to add a 100 items to your state:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
let item = {
        id: i,
        name: `User${i}`,
        age: Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 18) + 18)
      }
      items.push(item);
    }
    this.setState({items});

}
```